# Why does my resourcefolder get moved when creating a local repository?

Tags: java, git, libgdx, assets

So I've created a project with libgdx, and if you've used libgdx you'll know that it uses an assets folder in order to load images, sounds etc. My problem is that when I created a local repository the entire project folder got moved, along with the assetsfolder. Meaning that libgdx can't find the files.

When I was still in school we did this very same thing and this issue never arose. If I could get any help understanding this I'd be grateful.

Comment: What does "the entire project folder got moved" mean? Did you just clone the repository to a different location? Is the assets folder in the same place relative to the rest of the project, or did it somehow move to a different location within the project?

Comment: How did you create the local repository?  If via the command line, what command, specifically?  If via a tool, what tool?  Please elaborate on your issue